# Postgres autovacuum fails to start due to misconfiguration

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I am attempting to re-enable autovacuuming on a Postgres 9.1 instance and am receiving this in the db log:

```
2013-07-07 14:47:12 CDT WARNING:  autovacuum not started because of misconfiguration
2013-07-07 14:47:12 CDT HINT:  Enable the "track_counts" option.
```

Seems straightforward.  Except here's (the relevant segment of) my postgresql.conf file:

```
...

#track_activities = on
track_counts = on
#track_functions = none         # none, pl, all
#track_activity_query_size = 1024   # (change requires restart)
#update_process_title = on
#stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'

...

autovacuum = on     # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on' 
                    # requires track_counts to also be on.
#log_autovacuum_min_duration = -1   # -1 disables, 0 logs all actions and
                    # their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # actions running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds.
autovacuum_max_workers = 5     # max number of autovacuum subprocesses
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_naptime = 1min      # time between autovacuum runs
#autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50   # min number of row updates before
                    # vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50  # min number of row updates before
                    # analyze
#autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2   # fraction of table size before vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1  # fraction of table size before analyze
#autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000  # maximum XID age before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20ms    # default vacuum cost delay for
                    # autovacuum, in milliseconds;
                    # -1 means use vacuum_cost_delay
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1  # default vacuum cost limit for
                    # autovacuum, -1 means use
                    # vacuum_cost_limit
```

And here's what psql is reporting after restart:

```
mydb=# show autovacuum;
 autovacuum 
------------
 on
(1 row)

mydb=# show track_counts;
 track_counts 
--------------
 off
(1 row)
```

Any insight much appreciated!

Comment: Possibly the stats collector doesn't work. Aren't there any other message on startup?

Comment: Maybe a second copy of the `track_counts` parameter somewhere in the file? Did you try to comment out the `track_counts` option (as it defaults to on). You might also want to really confirm you are editing the correct file by running `select setting from pg_settings where name = 'config_file'`

Answer (score 2):

Double-check the log. Before the line you listed, do you get these lines:

```
LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Cannot assign requested address
LOG:  disabling statistics collector for lack of working socket
```

If that is the case, solve that problem first. What you most likely need to do to solve that, is add an entry like this to your /etc/hosts file:

127.0.0.1    localhost

It could very well be the case that the file currently assigns localhost to IPv6, with a line like this:

::1          localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback

If that is the case, you ALSO need to change that line to:

::1          ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback

Answer (score 1):

Did you reload the postgresql.conf file after making that change?
Eg, as a superuser ("postgres")

```
select pg_reload_conf();
```

Comment: Actually restarted the database.

Comment: Did you edit the correct postgresql.conf file? Are there any other lines around the error message that might give a clue? I personally haven't seen that error before, but what you've listed in your postgresql.conf looks fine to me.

Comment: I am afraid so.  There's only one instance on this system and if I comment out the autovacuum param, the error disappears.

Comment: What version of postgresql are you running?

Comment: Ummm, yeah, you certainly did. Oops!

Comment: I have no suggestions for you, other than to try on the pgsql-general mailing list which you can sign up for at http://www.postgresql.org/community/lists/

Comment: That was my thought as well.  Thanks, bma!